# Dynamic casting work both shared and weak pointers inside of template member function without code duplication

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, c++11

I have my Find method which I want to use both with shared and weak pointers. [Live example](https://wandbox.org/permlink/HstAFTasclIhCxi6)

```
using namespace std;

    template<typename value> 
    struct A 
    {
        template < typename T, typename F >
        T Find( F filterFunction)
        {
            for ( size_t i = 0; i < iteratableList.size(); i++)
            {
                auto castedTerrain = dynamic_pointer_cast<typename T::element_type>(iteratableList[i]);
                if ( castedTerrain && filterFunction(castedTerrain) )
                    return iteratableList[i];
            }
            return T();
        }

        std::vector<value> iteratableList;
    };

int main()
{
    {
        std::vector<std::shared_ptr<std::string>> names = {  make_shared<std::string>("needle"), make_shared<std::string>("manyOtherNames") } ; 
        A<std::shared_ptr<std::string>> iterateable{ names }; 
        iterateable.Find<std::shared_ptr<std::string>>([] ( std::shared_ptr<std::string> in ){ return  *in == "needle";});
    }

    // When I use weak pointer my Find function fails.
    //{
    //    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<std::string>> weakNames  ;
    //    for ( auto elem : names )
    //          weakNames.push_back(elem)
    //    A<std::weak_ptr<std::string>> iterateable{ weakNames }; 
    //    iterateable.Find<std::weak_ptr<std::string>>([] ( std::weak_ptr<std::string> in ){ return  *in == "needle";});
    //}
}
```

I know I can do something like 
 `std::is_same< std::weak_ptr ... >` and use `std::true_type` and `std::false_type` but I am curious if there is a better and cleaner way to achieve avoid code duplication just for `.lock()` method.

Comment: C++17's `if constexpr` would make this really easy to do

Comment: Sorry I am restricted to VS2010. I have some C++11 but not even all. But can you please write the solution with if constexpr I would love to read it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just have a template function you can use to obtain the "real" pointer.  The specialization for `std::shared_ptr` just returns the argument:

```
template <typename T>
struct resolve_pointer;

template <typename T>
struct resolve_pointer<std::shared_ptr<T>>
{
    static std::shared_ptr<T> resolve(std::shared_ptr<T> & p) const {
        return p;
    }
};

template <typename T>
struct resolve_pointer<std::weak_ptr<T>>
{
    static std::shared_ptr<T> resolve(std::weak_ptr<T> & p) const {
        return p.lock();
    }
};
```

Now your `Find` function, in place of `iteratableList[i]`, use `resolve_pointer<T>::resolve(iteratableList[i])`.

---

I'm a potato, an overloaded free function would work just as well and be a bit simpler to understand:

```
template <typename T>
std::shared_ptr<T> resolve_pointer(std::shared_ptr<T> & p) {
    return p;
}

template <typename T>
std::shared_ptr<T> resolve_pointer(std::weak_ptr<T> & p) {
    return p.lock();
}
```

---

If your goal is to be able to extend your code to provide interoperability with any strong/weak pointer pairs that have an implemented dynamic cast operation (shown here the std::strong/weak_ptr and boost::strong/weak_ptr), you can do this using a set of traits, like so... beware, dragons ahead:

```
// Defines a resolve static function to get a strong pointer from either
// a strong or a weak pointer.
template <typename T>
struct smart_pointer_info;

template <typename T>
struct smart_pointer_info<std::shared_ptr<T>>
{
    typedef std::shared_ptr<T> ptr_type;
    typedef T element_type;
    typedef std::shared_ptr<T> resolved_type;

    static resolved_type resolve(ptr_type & p) {
        return p;
    }
};

template <typename T>
struct smart_pointer_info<std::weak_ptr<T>>
{
    typedef std::weak_ptr<T> ptr_type;
    typedef T element_type;
    typedef std::shared_ptr<T> resolved_type;

    static resolved_type resolve(ptr_type & p) {
        return p.lock();
    }
};

template <typename T>
struct smart_pointer_info<boost::shared_ptr<T>>
{
    typedef boost::shared_ptr<T> ptr_type;
    typedef T element_type;
    typedef boost::shared_ptr<T> resolved_type;

    static resolved_type resolve(ptr_type & p) {
        return p;
    }
};

template <typename T>
struct smart_pointer_info<boost::weak_ptr<T>>
{
    typedef boost::weak_ptr<T> ptr_type;
    typedef T element_type;
    typedef boost::shared_ptr<T> resolved_type;

    static resolved_type resolve(ptr_type & p) {
        return p.lock();
    }
};

// Provides a static "cast" function that converts a strong pointer T
// into a strong point that points at an object of type D.
template <typename T, typename D>
struct smart_pointer_dynamic_cast;

template <typename T, typename D>
struct smart_pointer_dynamic_cast<std::shared_ptr<T>, D>
{
    typedef std::shared_ptr<T> ptr_type;
    typedef std::shared_ptr<D> cast_type;

    static cast_type cast(ptr_type & p) {
        return std::dynamic_pointer_cast<D>(p);
    }
};

template <typename T, typename D>
struct smart_pointer_dynamic_cast<boost::shared_ptr<T>, D>
{
    typedef boost::shared_ptr<T> ptr_type;
    typedef boost::shared_ptr<D> cast_type;

    static cast_type cast(ptr_type & p) {
        return boost::dynamic_pointer_cast<D>(p);
    }
};

// Helper so we can omit the template parameter for the source pointer type.
template <typename D>
struct dynamic_cast_helper
{
    template <typename P>
    static typename smart_pointer_dynamic_cast<typename smart_pointer_info<P>::resolved_type, D>::cast_type cast(P & p) {
        typename smart_pointer_info<P>::resolved_type r = smart_pointer_info<P>::resolve(p);

        return smart_pointer_dynamic_cast<typename smart_pointer_info<P>::resolved_type, D>::cast(r);
    }
};

// Then we might use it like so:
class A {
public:
    virtual void print() {
        std::cout << "A::print()" << std::endl;
    }
};

class B : public A {
public:
    virtual void print() {
        std::cout << "B::print()" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    auto x = std::make_shared<B>();
    std::weak_ptr<B> xw{x};

    auto y = boost::make_shared<B>();
    boost::weak_ptr<B> yw{y};

    dynamic_cast_helper<A>::cast(x)->print();
    dynamic_cast_helper<A>::cast(xw)->print();
    dynamic_cast_helper<A>::cast(y)->print();
    dynamic_cast_helper<A>::cast(yw)->print();

    return 0;
}
```

([Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/014fb252ba899cf8))

Your cast `dynamic_pointer_cast<typename T::element_type>(iteratableList[i])` then becomes `dynamic_cast_helper<typename smart_pointer_info<T>::element_type>::cast(iteratableList[i])` and all the types along the way get inferred by the compiler.

Comment: But what if there are many weak pointer type like boost weak pointer etc... . Is there easy way to make it work with all weak pointer whick has .lock function

Comment: @KadirErdemDemir You can use something like `template <typename T> decltype(std::declval<T>().lock()) resolve_pointer(T & p) { return p.lock(); }` but note that this doesn't guarantee that the result is an `std::shared_ptr`, so `dynamic_pointer_cast` may not work. However, we can build another template function that casts smart pointers and then provide overloads for boost's pointers.

Comment: A question do you know if Vs2010 has std::declval

Comment: I do not. If it doesn't, we can build a specialized trait to adapt boost pointers.

Comment: I think that is what I am looking for. Is it possible to update the answer. So readers can benefit from what you said as well.

Comment: Give me a few minutes to craft an example and I will update it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for help

Comment: Does VS2010 have `std::enable_if`?

Comment: It does. For example template<class T, class U>
typename std::enable_if<!std::is_same<std::shared_ptr<T>, std::tr1::shared_ptr<T>>::value, std::tr1::shared_ptr<T>>::type
    Cast( const std::tr1::shared_ptr<U>& spObject ) // rename from CastTerrainObject
{
    return std::tr1::dynamic_pointer_cast<T>(spObject);
} compiles

Comment: @KadirErdemDemir Updated.